# Does Power BI Rest API need only one Power BI Pro account for integrate reports, which will use for all end users?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are working Power BI Reports and we are new in Power BI. For embed Power BI reports in our web application we want to choose Rest APIs.

Is it possible that we subscribe only one Power BI Pro account and publish our all reports and it could be available for all end-users with access token?

Answer (score 0):

Technically that's possible, but I'm not sure if it's ok from licensing point of view.

I mean, Power BI Premium was released so that not all of the people in the organization should need Pro licenses. With Premium you're able to create and publish a report with a single Pro license and everybody else viewing the report can be Free-license users. The report might contain some Pro-freatures (like a gateway connection to on-premise) and it's still viewable to Free-users.

Premium isn't cheap, but it might work in some middle to large size organizations.

Another way to publish a report to multiple users is to use Publish to web -feature (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/), but it's got some limitations and security related issues.